# Access binary files that are stored in zipped form

Tags: r, binary-data

I have R code files that are made using readbin to make the map of drainage bin. But they are in the binary form and zipped. When I extracted manually there are numerous files. How can I access the R codes that are zipped in binary form in R programming?

I tried unzipping and tried to import all files but couldn't do it. IT said that the files are in binary form.

Comment: if the files are zipped you have to unzip them, use `readBin` to read binary format files into R.

Answer (score 1):

There's `unz` that allows reading zipped file without unzipping to disk, but you need to know the file name you are after inside the zip file, not sure whether this is what you need.

`help(unz)`:

> ‘unz’ reads (only) single files within zip files, in binary mode.
> The description is the full path to the zip file, with ‘.zip’
> extension if required.

> ... ‘unz’, ‘socketConnection’, ‘socketAccept’ and ‘serverSocket’
> return a connection object which inherits from class
> ‘"connection"’ and has a first more specific class.

The `unzip` function has a `list` option to list files in zip and does not extract them. Maybe you can achieve what you need by combining the two?